# Make input field uppercase with Javascript WITHOUT inline JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Ok, so I have a simple script (see below) which features an input-field where people can enter a query, and send this to a socrata-webservice to request specific data, which is then shown in an alert box. So far so good.

```
var kenteken = $("#kteken").val();
var datum = document.getElementById("vervaldatum")

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
$.getJSON("https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json",{kenteken: $("#kteken").val()},function(data, status){
    alert ("APK Vervaldatum: " + data[0].vervaldatum_apk);});
});
});
```

However, this socrata webservice only accepts queries in uppercase letters, and nothing else. Therefore, I want to make sure that everything anybody enters is automatically converted to uppercase, with all special characters removed. Now normally, I'd do that with inline JS like this:

`onKeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[W]/g,'');"`

I looked through several websites, including SO, but all solutions I found were variations on the above; all were solutions with inline JS. That's all well and good, but I'm currently working on a Wordpress site, which does not allow inline JS for 'security' reasons. Therefore, I'd have to include my 'uppercasing script' in the external JS file. I'm having trouble to get it to work though.

How would I change the existing .js file to ensure all entries in the `input` are automatically changed to uppercase only?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: why not just uppercase it when sending? `string.toUpperCase()` and in css: `text-transform:uppercase;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second parameter in the getJSON method from {kenteken: $("#kteken").val()} to {kenteken: $("#kteken").val().toUpperCase(‌​)} as suggested by Mettin and you will be good to go.

Comment: That worked. Knew it has to be something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS

we can use `text-transform: uppercase` . Use php functions to  convert it to uppercase in server side.

```
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I can't use CSS. The point is to send uppercase to the web service. CSS only makes it look like it's uppercase, but doesn't _actually_ make it uppercase. Edit: overlooked the PHP part. That might work, but I have next to no experience with PHP, so I'd prefer a JS solution

Comment: Is the input field part of a form?